# Room: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (void)

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-room

I have this query set up to return all the records from these tables and display the information on a recyclerview in android. the DB is set up using the Room persistence library aka SQLITE.

```
@Query
("SELECT moodBeforetable.userId, 
moodBeforetable.moodBefore, 
moodBeforetable.cbtId, 
cbtTable.automaticThought, 
cbtTable.twistedThinkingPK, 
cbtTable.challengeThought, 
cbtTable.rationalThought,  
cbtTable.date, 
moodAfterTable.moodAfter, 
twistedThinkingTable.twistedThinkingPK,
twistedThinkingTable.allOrNothing,  
twistedThinkingTable.blamingOthers,
twistedThinkingTable.catastrophizing, 
twistedThinkingTable.emotionalReasoning, 
twistedThinkingTable.fortuneTelling, 
twistedThinkingTable.labelling, 
twistedThinkingTable.magnifyingTheNegative, 
twistedThinkingTable.mindReading, 
twistedThinkingTable.minimisingThePositive,
twistedThinkingTable.overGeneralisation, 
twistedThinkingTable.selfBlaming, 
twistedThinkingTable.shouldStatement 

FROM moodBeforetable

JOIN cbtTable ON moodBeforetable.cbtId = cbtTable.cbtId
JOIN twistedThinkingTable ON cbtTable.cbtId = twistedThinkingTable.cbtId
JOIN moodAfterTable ON moodAfterTable.cbtId = cbtTable.cbtId

WHERE moodBeforetable.date >= datetime('now', '-1 year')
AND moodBeforetable.userId = :userId 
ORDER BY :date DESC")

LiveData<List<MoodBeforeTable>> moodLogsAll (int userId, String date);
```

When I try to compile the app I get the following error:

The query returns some columns which are not used by com.example.feelingfit.persistence.tables.MoodBeforeTable.
You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping.

Could anyone help me debug this and find out why the app wont compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is **Room** cannot map the result from your custom query to existing `MoodBeforeTable`. It is because your return type is `List<MoodBeforeTable>` but you have used joins using `TwistedThinkingTable` and `MoodAfterTable` and so on.

What you should do is create a new **POJO** like below:

```
public class MoodLogPojo() {
    private int userId;
    private String moodBefore;
    zprivate int cbtId;
    private String automaticThought;
    private int twistedThinkingPK;
    private String challengeThought;
    private String rationalThought;
    private String date;
    private String moodAfter;
    private int twistedThinkingPK;
    private String allOrNothing;
    private String blamingOthers;
    private String catastrophizing;
    private String emotionalReasoning;
    private String fortuneTelling;
    private String labelling;
    private String magnifyingTheNegative;
    private String mindReading;
    private String minimisingThePositive;
    private String overGeneralisation;
    private String selfBlaming;
    private String shouldStatement;

    // generate getters and setters too
    public void setSelfBlaming(Stirng selfBlming) {
        this.selfBlming = selfBlming
    }

    public String getSelfBlaming() { return selfBlaming; }

    // and so on ...

}
```

Then use this class as the return type like :

`LiveData<List<MoodLogPojo>> moodLogsAll (int userId, String date);`.

NOTE: Mind the `MoodLogPojo` class. Modify it accoring to the corresponding data types from each `Entity`.

Comment: Mate the new pojo class do the variables have the room annotations like @ColumnInfo? like is it a new table or simply just a class

Comment: It requires nothing it's just a plain old java object (POJO). Make a regular class and you're good to go.